# Dataframe Merge in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, I cannot get this merge to work correctly.

This Dataframe (rspars) has 2,000+ rows...

```
    rsparid  f1mult  f2mult  f3mult
 0        1   0.318   0.636   0.810
 1        2   0.348   0.703   0.893
 2        3   0.384   0.777   0.000
 3        4   0.296   0.590   0.911
 4        5   0.231   0.458   0.690
 5        6   0.275   0.546   0.839
 6        7   0.248   0.486   0.731
 7        8   0.430   0.873   0.000
 8        9   0.221   0.438   0.655
 9       11   0.204   0.399   0.593
```

When trying to join the above to a table based on the `rsparid` columns to this Dataframe...

```
            line_track  line_race rsparid
 line_date                               
 2013-03-23         TP         10    1400
 2013-02-23         GP          7     634
 2013-01-01         GP          7    1508
 2012-11-11        AQU          5      96
 2012-10-11        BEL          2     161
```

Using this...

```
 df = pd.merge(datalines, rspars, how='left', on='rsparid')
```

I get blanks..

```
   line_track  line_race rsparid  f1mult  f2mult  f3mult
 0         TP         10    1400     NaN     NaN     NaN
 1         TP         10    1400     NaN     NaN     NaN
 2         TP         10    1400     NaN     NaN     NaN
 3         GP          7     634     NaN     NaN     NaN
 4         GP         10     634     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Note, the "datalines" column can have thousands more rows than the rspars, thus the left join. I must be doing something wrong?

I also tried it this way...

```
 df = datalines.merge(rspars, how='left', on='rsparid')
```

**EXAMPLE #2**

I dropped the data down to a few rows...

rspars:

```
    rsparid  f1mult  f2mult  f3mult
 0     1400   0.216   0.435   0.656
```

datalines:

```
   rsparid
 0    1400
 1     634
 2    1508
 3      96
 4     161
 5    1011
 6    1007
 7     518
 8    1955
 9     678
```

Merging...

```
 datalines.merge(rspars, how='left', on='rsparid')
```

Output...

```
   rsparid  f1mult  f2mult  f3mult
 0    1400     NaN     NaN     NaN
 1     634     NaN     NaN     NaN
 2    1508     NaN     NaN     NaN
 3      96     NaN     NaN     NaN
 4     161     NaN     NaN     NaN
 5    1011     NaN     NaN     NaN
 6    1007     NaN     NaN     NaN
 7     518     NaN     NaN     NaN
 8    1955     NaN     NaN     NaN
 9     678     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Can you show a little bit of `datalines`?

Comment: The first shown Dataframe is rspars. The datalines table has dozens of fields one of which is rsparid.

Comment: I added some more info for clarity.

Comment: Your second example is not consistent. The `1400` row should have the values of `rspars` in it, and everything else will be `NaN` **because they don't have anything else in common in the `rsparid` column**. Are you sure you pasted the *exact* sequence of code that you executed?

Comment: I totally follow you on the what should be `NaN` and visa-versa. I copied this code directly from iPython Notebook.

Comment: This will happen if `datalines.rsparid` and `rspars.rsparid` are mixed types and don't have a well defined way to compare them. Can you make sure that they are not mixed?

Comment: What might be tripping you up is that the `repr` of small `DataFrame`s with strings (of integers) or integers looks the same and no `dtype` information is printed when frames are small. You can get this information (and more) for small frames by calling the `DataFrame.info` method, like so: `df.info()`. This will give you a nice summary of what's in the `DataFrame`.

Comment: Bingo! It was a mixed type error. Works fine now. I actually thought that was it earlier, but didn't realize I was formatting the one not causing the issue. Thank you so much for your help with this... it was a headache all morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NaN`s mean they have no values in `rsparid` in common. This can be tricky when merging things that may look the same when they `repr`

The repr of small `DataFrames` with strings (of integers) or integers looks the same and no `dtype` information is printed when frames are small. You can get this information (and more) for small frames by calling the `DataFrame.info()` method, like so: `df.info()`. This will give you a nice summary of what's in the `DataFrame` and what the `dtype`s of its columns are:

```
In [205]: datalines_int = DataFrame({'rsparid':[1400,634,1508,96,161,1011,1007,518,1955,678]})

In [206]: datalines_str = DataFrame({'rsparid':map(str,[1400,634,1508,96,161,1011,1007,518,1955,678])})

In [207]: datalines_int
Out[207]:
   rsparid
0     1400
1      634
2     1508
3       96
4      161
5     1011
6     1007
7      518
8     1955
9      678

In [208]: datalines_str
Out[208]:
  rsparid
0    1400
1     634
2    1508
3      96
4     161
5    1011
6    1007
7     518
8    1955
9     678

In [209]: datalines_int.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 1 columns):
rsparid    10  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1)

In [210]: datalines_str.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 1 columns):
rsparid    10  non-null values
dtypes: object(1)
```

**NOTE:** You'll notice a *slight* difference in the `repr`s here, most likely because of padding of numeric `DataFrame`s. Point is, no one would really be able to see that using this interactively, unless they were specifically looking for the difference.

Comment: I just added to the example how I indexed the rspar table to show the rsparid does exist. It's coming straight from a CSV file via `read_csv` and it's the rsparid's are definitely in there.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding `merge`. If there are no *values* in `datalines.rsparid` that are equal to the values in `rspars.rsparid` then you'll get `NaN`s because there's nothing to join on.

Comment: Hey if you check out my second example, where I reduced the data down to just what's there, I'm still having the issue.